# How to do objective c style assignments after renaming file to .mm

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

This code compiles in a .m file, but not in an .mm file:

```
CFDataRef nativeSocket = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
CFSocketNativeHandle *sock = (CFSocketNativeHandle *)CFDataGetBytePtr(nativeSocket);
```

The error message is:

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'CFDataRef' (aka 'const __CFData *') with an rvalue of type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *')
```

If I change the type of nativeSocket to CFTypeRef the error message becomes:

```
Candidate function not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') to 'CFDataRef' (aka 'const __CFData *')
```

Please tell me how to fix this. I can't seem to guess what to google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast the result from `CFWriteStreamCopyProperty()` to the proper type:

```
CFDataRef nativeSocket = (CFDataRef)CFWriteStreamCopyProperty((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
CFSocketNativeHandle *sock = (CFSocketNativeHandle *)CFDataGetBytePtr(nativeSocket);
```

It's probably safer to extract the native handle this way, though:

```
CFSocketNativeHandle sock;
CFDataGetBytes(nativeSocket, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(sock)), (UInt8*)&sock);
```

That avoids any issue with the data object's byte pointer being misaligned. Also, it ensures that you don't try to deference the byte pointer implicitly (by doing `*sock`) after the data object has been released.